# pythonで正方形の画像をタイルのように任意の順番で表示したい

Tags: python, matplotlib

wspaceやhspaceで隙間を消しているつもりだが実行後の画像が不自然な隙間があいてしまう

```
def ketugou(path, outpath, zyunban, tate, yoko):
  
  d = []

  for i in range(tate * yoko):
    img = Image.open(path+"/chunk_"+str(int(zyunban[i]))+".png")
    img = np.asarray(img)
    d.append(img)

  fig, ax = plt.subplots(tate, yoko, figsize=(10, 10))
  fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

  for i in range(tate):
    for j in range(yoko):
      ax[i, j].xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
      ax[i, j].yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
      ax[i, j].imshow(d[yoko*i+j], cmap="bone")

  plt.savefig(outpath,format = os.path.splitext(outpath)[1][1:],dpi=360)
  print('finished')
```

Comment: 手元の環境では`ax[i, j].imshow(d[yoko*i+j], cmap="bone", aspect="auto")`に変更し、`imshow`の引数[`aspect="auto"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43822260)を追加することで解消しましたがいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。上手くいきました。

Comment: 解決済であれば質問をクローズしましょう。

Comment: 質問の内容がわからなくなっていたので、ロールバックしておきました。

Answer (score 2):

[`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html)の引数に`aspect="auto"`を追加することで解消できるかもしれません。

上記のリンク先によると、引数省略時には`aspect="equal"`となりアスペクト比1を保証するよう描画されます。
これによって描画時に1ピクセルの隙間ができる可能性があります。

[本家SOの類似質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43821302/8248751)